# Strange behaviour of autohotkey loop

Tags: loops, sequence, autohotkey

I am trying to do a very simple thing with autohotkey:

- reload a browser window
- wait 5 seconds
- send mouse wheel down 6 times
- wait 15 minutes
- repeat

The script I tried is:

```
#Persistent
Loop,
{
Send {F5}
Sleep, 5000
Send, {WheelDown 6}
Sleep 900000
}
```

For some reason however, it doesn't work as expected.
It seems that it waits, after sends WheelDown and immediately reloads (sends F5).
I tried to change the sequence to no avail.

Could you please advise where might be the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: I see no issue with the code, I tested it on my side and it works as intended.

Comment: The window is active, but it simply doesn't work as expected.

It seems to scroll, reload and after just keeps reloading without scrolling.

Comment: I can confirm Yane's results; it worked for me as intended. There is inconsistent comma usage, but AHK is flexible enough to accept this. Is this your whole script?

Comment: It is strange really. I experimented with different options, came back to this one and it worked. As it didn't at certain point, I am unsure why...

Comment: Make sure your mouse is over the correct window at the time of scrolling or else the WheelDown may not be appropriately applied to the active window (particularly if you use a utility to scroll inactive windows with the wheel when the mouse is over the inactive window). Use `Send {Click 100, 200, 0}` to first position the mouse without clicking.

Comment: Btw, why aren't you using down arrows to move down the page? Try it with `Send, {Down 18}` (assuming each wheel moves 3 lines, the default). In this case, you will probably also want to make sure the window is active with `WinActivate`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Per my comments:

```
#Persistent
Loop,
{
WinActivate, Your Window Title ; optional, but good practice
Sleep, 250
Send, {F5}
Sleep, 5000
Send, {Click 100, 200, 0} ; adjust the position so over the window
Send, {WheelDown 6}
; Or substitute the prior two lines with (remove the first ;)
; Send, {Down 18} ; adjust the number of lines
Sleep, 900000
}
```

Hth,

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure if the additional sleep of 250 milliseconds or the mouse pointer placement did the trick, but now it seems the script is working more consistently.